# Como percorrer uma tabela com várias linhas e selecionar apenas uma específica?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou tentando fazer que, ao clicar em uma `tr` com um id único, abrir um `slideToggle` com uma outra tabela embaixo da mesma linha que foi clicado. Eu fiz esse exemplo abrindo a primeira e a segunda linha, só que eu queria fazer algo dinâmico.

Até consegui fazer com todos de uma vez mas queria dessa forma que falei. Se alguém poder me ajudar, agradeço.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.slide').hide();
  var contar = $('.contar');
  var qtd = 0;
  contar.each(function() {
    qtd++;
  });

  $('#' + 1).click(function() {
    $('.slide' + 1).slideToggle();
  });
  $('#' + 2).click(function() {
    $('.slide' + 2).slideToggle();
  });

});
```

```html
<tr class="info aba" id="<?php echo $cont ?>">
  <td class="labelAzul">
    <?php echo $listaPedidosSemanais[ "NOME"]?>
  </td>
  <td class="labelAzul">
    <?php echo $listaPedidosSemanais[ "SERVIÇO"]?>
  </td>
  <td class="labelAzul">
    <?php echo $listaPedidosSemanais[ "OPERADORA"]?>
  </td>
  <td class="labelAzul"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="abrir('pedidos_Semanais_prescricao.php?id=<?php echo $listaPedidosSemanais[" ID "]?>&dtIni=<?php echo $_POST["periodoInicial "]?>&dtFim=<?php echo $_POST["periodoFinal "]?>','600','600')">Prescrição</a>
  </td>
  <td class="labelAzul"></td>
</tr>
<tr id="<?php echo $cont ?>">
  <thead>
    <th class="labelAzul slide  <?php echo " slide " . $cont ?>" data-field="PRESCRICAO" data-sortable="true">PRESCRIÇÃO</th>
    <th class="labelAzul slide <?php echo " slide " . $cont ?>" data-field="DATAINICIO IRGENCIA" data-sortable="true">DATA INICIO VIRGENCIA</th>
    <th class="labelAzul slide <?php echo " slide " . $cont ?>" data-field="DATAFIMVIRGENCIA" data-sortable="true">DATA FIM VIRGENCIA</th>
    <th class="labelAzul slide <?php echo " slide " . $cont ?>" data-field="DATALIBERACAO" data-sortable="true">DATA LIBERAÇÃO</th>
    <th class="labelAzul slide <?php echo " slide " . $cont ?>" data-field="DIFERENCA" data-sortable="true">DIFERENÇA</th>
  </thead>
  <?php $qryPrescricao=$ dao->listar_prescricoes($listaPedidosSemanais["ID"], $_POST["periodoInicial"], $_POST["periodoFinal"] ); $qtdPrescricao = count($qryPrescricao); foreach ($qryPrescricao as $pacientes){ ?>

  <tbody class="contar">
    <td style="text-align: center" class="labelAzul slide <?php echo " slide " . $cont ?>">
      <?php echo $pacientes[ "IDPRESCRICAO"]?>
    </td>
    <td style="text-align: center" class="labelAzul slide <?php echo " slide " . $cont ?>">
      <?php echo $pacientes[ "DT_INI_VIRGENCIA"]?>
    </td>
    <td style="text-align: center" class="labelAzul slide <?php echo " slide " . $cont ?>">
      <?php echo $pacientes[ "DT_FIM_VIRGENCIA"]?>
    </td>
    <td style="text-align: center" class="labelAzul slide <?php echo " slide " . $cont ?>">
      <?php echo $pacientes[ "DT_LIBERACAO"]?>
    </td>
    <td style="text-align: center" class="labelAzul slide <?php echo " slide " . $cont ?>">
      <?php $duracao=$ funcao->diferenca_data_hora($pacientes["DT_LIBERACAO"], $pacientes["DT_INI_VIRGENCIA"]); $dia = (int) substr($duracao, 0, 2); $tam = strlen($duracao); if($dia >= 2 && $tam >= 11){ $classHoraUtil = 'labelVermelho'; $fora_prazo++;} else{ $classHoraUtil =
      'labelAzul'; $dentro_prazo++;} echo "
      <label class=".$classHoraUtil.">".$duracao."</label>"; ?>
    </td>
    <?php }?>
  </tbody>
</tr>
```

Comment: Você está usando algum framework ? Bootstrap ou algo do tipo ?

Comment: tente capturar o click nas `tr` com 
`$("tr").on('click', function() {
    $('.slide' + $(this).attr('id')).slideToggle();
});`

Answer (score 1):

Olá !

Você não precisa necessáriamente usar Jquery para fazer isso, em um código semelhante meu fiz o seguinte:

```
<tr>
    <td><a id='".$id."' href='#'  onClick='return slide(this.id);'>Nome Exemplo</a></td>    
</tr>
```

Então no JavaScript recuperei desta forma:

```
 function slide(id) { 
  $('.slide' + id).slideToggle();
 }
```

Caso esteja trabalhando com Bootstrap, pode usar essa lib que tranforma a tr em um link clicável: http://www.jasny.net/bootstrap/javascript/#rowlink

Edit: Talvez para exibir a informação abaixo da linha, seja interessante usar a classe collapse do bootstrap.

```
<a href="#demo" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse">Simple collapsible</a>
  <div id="demo" class="collapse">
      Texto Exemplo
  </div>
```

Abraços,

Comment: Olá Lucas, dessa forma ele mostra as informações para todas as tabelas e eu queria que funcionasse só em baixo da que fosse clicada. Muito obrigado pela a ajuda.

Comment: sim, eu estou usando Bootstrap.

Comment: Ah sim, achei que a dúvida era sobre não precisar programar manualmente a chamada de cada registro, para exibir a informação abaixo da linha, talvez seja interessante usar a classe collapse do bootstrap, basta criar uma div com a `class="collapse"` e no seu link colocar `data-toggle="collapse"` como no exemplo que vou adicionar à resposta